# How to prevent Wordpress from showing Google Org Chart row lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-api

I am using the [Google Org Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) and I am having an issue with row lines being displayed once I put this into WordPress (see image). Using the same code outside of the company Wordpress site does not show these lines. One thing I find intriguing is how three of the lines are light blue while the rest are grey. I tried using this as a clue in my debugging, but I still was not able to turn up anything.

Is there anything that I can add in the CSS for that page to override this and prevent those lines from showing?

[image: Row lines displayed]

Comment: It is probably inheriting styles from your theme CSS. And it is most probably your table styles. Without some code or a URL to look at it will be difficult to assist. One thing you can do is inspect the code via the browser inspector. That will show you where the styles are coming from

Answer (score 0):

It is probably inheriting styles from your theme CSS. And it is most probably your table styles. Without some code or a URL to look at it will be difficult to assist. One thing you can do is inspect the code via the browser inspector. That will show you where the styles are coming from.

You can try adding this code to your Customizer Custom CSS section to see if that helps.

```
 td, tr{
    border:none;
 }
```

This code will remove the borders from all your tables though so if it works for you try adding this code instead.

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-table tr{
    border:none;
 }
```

Comment: There's definitely something in the primary css files that's causing this, but I'm unable  to find the conflict. I looked in my revision history and had already tried the google-visualization entry into the style code. Neither the overall td, tr code line nor the google-visualization code line had any affect. I'm still combing through the debugger console, but still shooting blanks.